# Why the `Train net output` loss and `iteration loss` are the same during training with caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I am training AlexNet on my own data using caffe. One of the issues I see is that the *"Train net output"* loss and *"iteration loss"* are nearly the same in the training process. Moreover, this loss has fluctuations.
like:

> ```
> ...
> ...Iteration 900, loss 0.649719
> ...    Train net output #0: loss = 0.649719 (* 1 = 0.649719 loss ) 
> ...    Iteration 900, lr = 0.001
> ...Iteration 1000, loss 0.892498
> ...    Train net output #0: loss = 0.892498 (* 1 = 0.892498 loss ) 
> ...    Iteration 1000, lr = 0.001
> ...Iteration 1100, loss 0.550938
> ...    Train net output #0: loss = 0.550944 (* 1 = 0.550944 loss ) 
> ...    Iteration 1100, lr = 0.001
> ...
> ```

1. should I see this fluctuation?
2. As you see the difference between reported losses are not significant. Does it show a problem in my training?

---

my `solver` is:

```
net: "/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 1999
test_interval: 10441
base_lr: 0.001
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 100
max_iter: 208820
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10441
snapshot_prefix: "/caffe_alexnet_train"
solver_mode: GPU
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31840488/1714410

Answer (score 5):

1. Caffe uses [Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) method for training the net. In the long run, the loss decreases, however, locally, it is perfectly normal for the loss to fluctuate a bit.
2. The reported *"iteration loss"* is the weighted sum of all loss layers of your net, averaged over [`average_loss`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L152) iterations. On the other hand, the reported *"train net output..."* reports each net output from the current iteration only.
   In your example, you did not set `average_loss` in your `'solver'`, and thus `average_loss=1` by default. Since you only have one loss output with `loss_weight=1` the reported *"train net output..."* and  *"iteration loss"* are the same (up to display precision).

To conclude: your output is perfectly normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shai for the answer. Could you please tell me how I can define that `average_loss` in my `solver` too? I checked it in `googlenet` and it was `like average_loss: 40`. Is it an initial value for that?

Comment: @user6726469 the default value is 1. I usually set it to the same value of `display` parameter. It's up to you to decide what interval to average.